# Bootstrap js is adding hidden style display none to my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hidden, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap v5 and it appears to be preventing my images from loading. I am using images on other parts of my site that load without issue.

I write the following in html `<img border="0" src="example.com/img/kitties-long.png" id="placedTop">`

When I view my webpage through the developer tools. It reads: `<img border="0" src=example.com/img/kitties-long.png" id="placedTop" hidden="" style="display: none !important;">`

Basically `hidden="" style="display: none !important;"` is being added against my desire.

I went into the bootstrap css file and found `[hidden]{display:none !important}`.

I have:

1. removed the `!important` from this piece and my images are still hidden
2. removed the `!important` from this piece and added `display: block !important` into my css file but the images are still hidden
3. deleted the `[hidden]` element from the bootstrap css file and then other pieces of my webpage failed to operate properly
4. seen there are ways to possibly attack this with jQuery but I do not understand how to physically write the entire script code on my HTML page.

I have seen writing `$("tag or #id or .className here").show()` should work but I don't understand what or where this needs to be typed to work. I have seen writing it with  tags in my head section or writing it in a .js file.

This is the whole html where my information appears:

```
<div class="ap-horz aboveCentral">
  <div class="ap-container" id="tAp">
    <img border="0" src="example.com/img/kitties-long.png" id="placedTop">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have written a .js file to try to find and block the code from loading but that does not appear to work either. The unhide.js file is:

```
function unhideFunction() {
var hidingVar = document.getElementById("placedTop");
if (window.getComputedStyle(hidingVar).style.display === "none") {
    document.getElementById("placedTop").style.display = "block !important";
    document.getElementById("placedBot").style.display = "block !important";
}
}
```

I have changed the order of my javascript files at the bottom of my html to put the unhide.js on top of the bootstrap.js and also tried them the other way.

I am pretty new with javascript and have very little jQuery experience. I understand html and css pretty well but do not understand why only this image is becoming hidden and not others.

Comment: Are you sure that this is bootstrap? Try removing bootstrap CSS and see if any other plugins cause your images to hide, also the bit of CSS you just removed is not the one causing the CSS to be added

Comment: I have turned all of my css and js off and it still happens

Comment: So it's not bootstrap , it's something else, extensions?? Try opening with browser extensions disabled or in incognito

Comment: Same issue in Firefox, IE, Edge, and Chrome incognito

Comment: @Christoph can you share he complete code.

Comment: @Christoph There is no image on this URL `example.com/img/kitties-long.png`

Comment: @Christoph try changing the img source to `https://source.unsplash.com/random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be caused by AdBlocker (at least inside Opera browser). For me it blocks showing images of Amazon products from //ws-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?.... (by adding the same style="display: none !important;")
If I switch off AdBlocker extension, images appear

Answer (score 0):

Add *Inline style* in your `div` tag and imported in that it will override *bootstrap* style.

```
<img border="0" src="example.com/img/kitties-long.png" id="placedTop" style="display: none !important;">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my Anti-Virus extension on Chrome. I had to White List the website. I hope this helps others.